How to make smooth rotation of one object after another using godot 4 and GDscript?
I have a tank on the scene with a turret attached as a child object. I also have a camera on the scene that rotates using a script, I need the tank turret to smoothly rotate as the camera rotates.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to smoothly rotate the turret after the camera, so that when the tank turns, the turret stays in place (because the camera does not rotate)
I implemented something similar, but when the tank rotates, the turret rotates with it, but since the camera does not rotate at this moment, now there is free space between the rotation of the camera and the turret.
Tank scene tree: https://i.imgur.com/BgwBz0q.png
(to do camera node independent of the parent object i use this code at camera node script)
func _ready():
Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)
set_as_top_level(true)

Rotation that i need: https://youtu.be/23IdDtPB4t0

Is this a code question? Please show some. Also revise your title to ask a clear, specific question without tags. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If I correctly understood your question, you have a tank which is composed of a body, which moves with WASD, and a turret linked with the camera which move with mouse movement. Since you haven't posted code, I suppose you wanna hear the concept more than the code.
The problem is how you structured your tree. You said:

I have a tank on the scene with a turret attached as a child object

Since the turret is a child of the tank, EVERY rotation, POSITION, scale update on father are applied to childs (for Godot's logic). So this is a problem, because if you rotate the tank, even the turret will rotate even if you haven't moved the mouse.
In order to fix this, you should have a tree where the father is a generic Node with two childs (two nodes), one for the turret and the camera and one for the body, both with their own script to change with user input.
This should fix this

I implemented something similar, but when the tank rotates, the turret rotates with it,

To do something "smoothly rotate" I suppose you want a system where camera rotates and after a "delay" turret rotates too. You can do so using lerp. I link to the official documentation for more
As isherwood mentioned, your question is incomplete. Please, provide more informations (and some code) if you need more assistance/what I said is not what you are searching for.
Greetings

I add more information to my question, can you advise anything?

Godot follows philosphy of "function down, signals up", meaning both use more signals than functions and call functions when you go down the tree and signals when you go up. That said, I still don't know what you wrote in VehicleBody3D, which probably is affecting rotation of your camera too. Idk what set_as_top_level does, but you are breaking Godot principle in this way. Instead, create two separated node with VehicleBody as only parent and modify position with a script attached to body node and rotation with script attached to head node (Single responsability). Greetings
